# jquery .replaceWith() not playing nice with .clone() in IE7

Tags: jquery, debugging, internet-explorer-7, replace, clone

I'm using jQuery to created a linked TOC that appears in a dialog box. The function I wrote to do so finds all the `h4`'s in the page and

- gives them `id`s to link to
- adds some numbering display info
- clones them
- turns the clones into `li`s
- wraps the inner text in anchor tags
- finds the anchors adds a click function to the anchors to close the dialog
- adds `title`s and `href`s to the anchors so the links point to the original `h4`s
- goes back to the `li`s
- appends the `li`s to a `ol` the in dialog `div`

However, in **IE7**, the cloned `h4`s are not getting turned in `li`s. Works in FireFox. In IE7, everything happens as it does in FireFox, just that the the `.replaceWith()` is seemingly ignore... why?

Looks like this:

```
$('#content h4').each(function(index) {
   index = index + 1;
    $(this)
   .attr('id', 'tutorial_' + index)
   .before(function() {
            return '<div class="how_to">HOW TO<div><span>' + index + '</span></div></div>';
        })
  .clone()
  .replaceWith("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>")
  .wrapInner("<a></a>")
  .find('a')
    .click(function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    })
    .attr({
        'title': 'jump to ' + $(this).text(),
        'href': '#tutorial_' + index
    })
   .end()
  .appendTo('#dialog ol')
 });
```

In action at: http://f1shw1ck.com/jquery_sandbox/tutorials.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why people love so much cloning... :)

I would do something like

```
$('#content h4').each(function(index) {
   index = index + 1;
    $(this)
   .attr('id', 'tutorial_' + index)
   .before(function() {
            return '<div class="how_to">HOW TO<div><span>' + index + '</span></div></div>';
        })
  .clone()
  .html("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>")
  .wrapInner("<a></a>")
  .find('a')
    .click(function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    })
    .attr({
        'title': 'jump to ' + $(this).text(),
        'href': '#tutorial_' + index
    })
   .end()
  .appendTo('#dialog ol')
 });
```

But that's just me :)

**EDIT:** After reading "a lot" about replaceWith() - there seems to be unresolved bug with IE7 & IE6 since... forever. So I discarded my function, took yours and replaced `replaceWith` with `html` - which works in this case the way you want, i.e. replace item's html and return itself.

As for replaceWith, you probably ran into one of web vs. IE7 bugs ;)

Comment: Doesn't work. Look at `.add("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>")` -- `$(this)` refers to  `$('#dialog ol')` in what you wrote. There is no text there. But I see what you are trying to do. I can get the text and put it in a variable and put that between the `<li>`. That's not my question though, I want to know why what I wrote doesn't work. Is it a bug or not, etc...

Comment: well, i just tried to show you different approach, when you'll have enough of yours :) And I also edited code.

Comment: I also see you put that code on - there is also mistake - after $(content ol), there are two fullstops (dots) - should be one - already edited here.

Comment: Thanks for the new tack. I would like to see why what I did doesn't work though...

Comment: Hmm. Going to assume its a bug. Thanks for suggesting the alternate route.

Answer (score 0):

There are some typo in that page script

http://f1shw1ck.com/jquery_sandbox/tutorials.html

line 43:

```
$('#dialog ol').
```

you have to delete that dot

line 61:

I dont think that **});** should be there!

Comment: Oops, that was me trying Adam Kiss' solution. He corrected. I restored to my original code, which works, except the replaceWith() is ignored in IE7, like I first said.